# IndexError: index 1491188345 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1491089723

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe,df with 646585 rows and 3 columns which looks like :

```
index      inp       aco         count                
  0       2.3.6.   dp-ptp-a2f   22000
  1       2.3.12.  ft-ptp-a2f   21300
  2       2.5.9.   dp-ptp-a2f   21010
  3       0.8.0.   dp-ptp-a4f   20000
  4       2.3.6.   ft-ptp-a2f   19000               
  5       2.3.6.   ff-ptp-a2f   18500        
  ...                            ...
  ...                            ...   
  ...                            ...
```

I tried to pivot the dataframe using the code:

```
df1=df.pivot_table(values='count', index='inp', columns='aco',fill_value=0)
print(df1)
```

but I got

```
IndexError: index 1491188345 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1491089723
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [open Pandas issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10582) describing this error.

AFAIK currently there is no solution/workaround provided, except reducing the data set

Comment: Has this been resolved? Should I assume that it hasn't since the issue is still open?

Comment: @AlexMetsai, the current status says - "Open". I guess the pandas team would change the status if they would fix it )

Comment: So it's not a memory issue, right? Huge dataframes cause int32 fault, no matter how large your RAM is?

Comment: @AlexMetsai, actually it could be caused by memory error. You can have a look here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10554

Comment: I see. I was thinking of openining a question, but I don't think that I could be specific enough. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: @MaxU Can we use PySpark instead of using Pandas? Will that be a good workaround??

Comment: @PurushothamanSrikanth, at least we can try) Unfortunately there is no `.pivot_table()` in PySpark, so one would have to do it manually: `df.groupby(...).pivot(...)...`