# Trying to pivot a large dataframe, but get 'IndexError: index 875914235 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 875909652'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I'm trying to pivot this dataframe ('refined_dataset'):

[image: dataframe]

Like this:

```
movieUser_df = refined_dataset.pivot(
    index='userID',
     columns='primaryTitle',
      ## Replacing all movies users haven't rated with a rating of 0
      values='rating').fillna(0)
```

And it returns the error: `IndexError: index 875914235 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 875909652`

I've done this exact method with almost identical (but much smaller) datasets in the past, I looked up for why I might be having this problem and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492451/indexerror-index-1491188345-is-out-of-bounds-for-axis-0-with-size-1491089723) post from 5 years ago where it's explained that it's an ongoing Pandas issue. Apart from a couple of comments on that post, of which the most recent was two years ago and I don't know if there's any updates since, I can't find others talking about this problem or possible solutions. Does anyone know if this Pandas issue is indeed my problem, and whether it is or isn't, if there's any ways I can try and do it differently?

Comment: Prior to getting the error you have reported, I get this warning: `pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py:130: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
  num_cells = num_rows * num_columns`.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is that if you're using conventional pandas methods to create a pivot table with too many rows and columns, even if most of the values use a fill default for missing `row, column` pairs (in your example, a rating of 0 for all movies users haven't rated), the total number of values can cause integer overflow and also surpass available memory.

The solution is to use [sparse data structures](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661604/efficiently-create-sparse-pivot-tables-in-pandas) has an answer that walks through how to do this using `csr_matrix` from `scipy.sparse` and `CategoricalDtype` from `pandas.api.types`, but it relies on `pd.SparseDataFrame` which has been removed from pandas in recent years.

Here is code that should be able to handle the example in your question.

```py
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

rcLabel, vLabel = ('userID', 'titleID'), 'rating'
rcCat = [CategoricalDtype(sorted(df[col].unique()), ordered=True) for col in rcLabel]
rc = [df[column].astype(aType).cat.codes for column, aType in zip(rcLabel, rcCat)]
mat = csr_matrix((df[vLabel], rc), shape=tuple(cat.categories.size for cat in rcCat))
dfOut = ( pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(
    mat, index=rcCat[0].categories, columns=rcCat[1].categories) )
```

Code to generate sample input:

```py
from random import randrange
dfLen = 3_500_000
titles = [f'tt{randrange(0,10_000_000):07}' for _ in range(dfLen)]
df = pd.DataFrame({
'titleID':titles,
'userID':[f'ur{randrange(0,67_000_000):08}' for _ in range(dfLen)],
'primaryTitle':titles,
'rating':[float(randrange(1,11)) for _ in range(dfLen)]})
```

Here are the assumptions I have made:

- the input dataframe is named `df`, the pivoted output is named `dfOut`
- there are 67 million unique users
- there are 10 million unique titles
- there are 3.5 million rows (i.e., `userID, titleID` pairs)

Observations:

- In a dense (non-sparse) pivot, this could create as many as 3.5 million squared or about 10 trillion values, in comparison with about 3.5 million values in a sparse representation.
- In my example (which selects users and titles at random from within the assumed populations), the sparse result dimensions are [3410055 rows x 2952380 columns] and the `info()` method reports `memory usage: 195.1+ MB`.